# can't edit a JFrame form anymore

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I have several JFrames which i have previously created, normally when i want to adjust anything related to the GUI i right click on the Frame name into my application -> Edit - and Start editing

Now suddenly all my JFrames became only CLASSES like if was created them from the begging as a Java Class not JFrame Form and i only have access to the generated code by netbeans GUI.

How can i roll them back to their previous type or extension so i can edit the GUI though the drag and drop features of netbeans?

Comment: Not clear as to what your trying to achieve? do you have the .java files of all your JFrames? can you post the genrated code by netbeans GUI?

Comment: Well look this photo please and notice the ICON differences of both files -> http://2.ii.gl/bWsouj.png
AddMacroForm file is .java but it can be EDITED as a JFrame
While the AdminHome.java is not editable using the JFrame GUI Builder, even that it was created through it!!

Also here is screenshot of the Right Click on each file.

1st file http://3.ii.gl/iFbrKy.png
2nd file http://3.ii.gl/6Stt0j.png
Notice the "Edit" option? it was exists for first file as well but not anymore.